# c# - Set private field in inherit class

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, multiple-inheritance

Okay so I have a program that contains multiple classes some of which inherit each other. The basic layout looks like this:

```
public class Foo2
{
    public string junk1 = "bleh"; // Not useful
}

public class Foo1 : Foo2
{
    private int num = 2; // I want to access this
    private string junk2 = "yo";
}

public class Foo : Foo1
{
    public string junk3 = "no";
}
```

Now in another I have as follows:

```
public class access // I used Reflection
{
    private Foo2 test = new Foo(); // The only thing important here is that test is Foo2
    
    private void try1() // This was my first attempt(It didn't work)
    {
        Foo tst = (Foo)test;
        tst.GetType().GetField("num", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(tst, 5);
    }
    
    private void try2() // Second attempt also didn't work
    {
        Foo1 tst = (Foo1)test;
        tst.GetType().GetField("num", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(tst, 5);
    }
}
```

None of the methods I tried worked.

Comment: You can not cast in that way, your code will throw an `InvalidCastException` on `(Foo)test` or `(Foo1)test`.

Comment: You created an instance of Foo2. That class does not contain a member called num. There is absolutely no way to write to that field. Also reflection will not help.

Comment: If you only want to access this field in a derived class like the title said (your code doesn't try to access in derived class) use the normal OOP way by implementing a protected property that controls the access to your field. In that case you don't need reflection.

Comment: Thought of it too but `protected` doesn't help either when accessing the field/property from outside the class. @Verarind

Comment: Guys I fixed the mistake in my code above so yea

Comment: @PatrickHofman as I said. The question title told me that he only want to access in a derived class. The code tries to access that field from anywhere else.

Comment: I know @Verarind. The question is ambiguous.

Comment: Eww, reflection?! Is designing your classes properly to avoid using reflection an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Foo2` does not derive from `Foo1` or `Foo` so it doesn't have the derived field `num`. That's it, period.

If your `tst` was `Foo1` it would have worked:

```
Foo1 test = new Foo1();

test.GetType().GetField("num", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(test, 5);
```

---

And since private fields are type-specific, in the last case you need to use the correct type:

```
typeof(Foo1).GetField("num", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(test, 5);
```

Comment: When I did test is Foo1 it returned true same when I did test is Foo, I modified things from Foo successfully and it worked but this is the first time trying it on Foo1 and failed

Comment: Maybe your sample code is wrong, but this is never going to work this way. It will work if `test` is either `Foo` or `Foo1` but not `Foo2`.

Comment: I just double checked it is exactly like that maybe it helps if I tell you I am using .Net framework 2.0 in unity but I doubt that will have any effect

Comment: No, that doesn't matter. Your inheritance (or lack of it) is causing the problem.

Comment: Okay I fixed the mistake in my code on top can you help now. Sorry about that

Comment: @EliteInfinity so Patrick was right. You should accept his answer.